# jar file that deletes itself after execution

Tags: java, jar

I'm creating a jar file that self-updates.

On it's execution, it'll check an external website and download a new jar if it's more recent. That's not a problem.

However, I need the current executing jar (the one that detected itself is older) to be deleted whenever the new jar is downloaded. For that I tried using `File.deleteOnExit()` as follows:

```
File currentJar = new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
currentJar.deleteOnExit();
System.exit(0);
```

The thing is: After exiting the application, the old jar file is still there.

I don't want to use bat or sh files, as this should be a single-jar application.

**How can I create a jar file that self-deletes after it's execution?**

Comment: What about having the old jar start the new jar, then stop itself, and the new jar does a check on startup for old jars and deletes them? I don't think you can have a running jar delete itself, because the jar file is in use.

Answer (score 0):

On `Windows` is not possible (the `OS` will lock executing files, so you cannot self-delete on exit), on a `Unix` `OS` however you can (only on a `JVM` post 1.6... this time for a classloader problem, not `OS` limitation). Best solution is using a `.bat` or `.sh` script to make sure to circumvent any `OS` or `JVM` limitations.